# How big is the Inti Raymi celebration in Peru?

Tags: peru, festivals, cusco

Considering traveling to Peru in June and read about the Inti Raymi festival on June 24 which seems to be centered in Cusco. Trying to determine whether it would be worth it to plan around the trip for this.

Some sources like [Frommer’s](https://www.frommers.com/destinations/cusco/attractions/special-events--festivals) talk about it being before and after this day. [Peru.travel](https://www.peru.travel/en/masperu/inti-raymi-the-most-important-festival-of-the-inca-empire) gives the impression that it’s mostly a single show in two locations.

Curious if anyone can comment on how widespread and large these celebrations are? If one were to travel there a few days before, would they easily stumble upon celebrations and/or events just walking around the Cusco? Or is it more isolated especially given the pandemic?